# Laravel: change log path to include user folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I use Laravel 5.1 and I am trying to intercept the default logger configuration (Monolog) and save logs to a different path that includes user name.

The current logs are saved to storage/logs/laravel.log.

The wanted paths are as follows

**Authenticated Users:** storage/logs/[username]/[date]_[api_path].log

Other user logs can be saved under storage/logs/guest/[date]_[api_path].log

**ServiceProvider Approach**

Have a **LogServiceProvider** and where I can modify each request and set the path as wanted.

```
public function boot(Request $request)
{

    $log = new Logger('View Logs');
    $user = \Auth::User()->getName(); // ERROR - uninitialized
    $path = 'storage/logs/'.$user.'/mylogfile.log'; // doesn't matter API path
    $log ->pushHandler(new StreamHandler($path, Logger::INFO));
    ...
 }
```

The problem with this approach, the Auth::user() seems to be uninitialized.

**Why does this happen and how do I solve this?**

Answer (score 1):

You might need to wrap it in an if statement, such as:

```
if ( Auth::check() ) {
  // Do auth stuff
}
else {
  // Do unauth stuff
}
```

Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

*This is because Auth has not been initialized and it is too early to call.*

#### There is example way to solve:

- Create log initializer, and call it from **middleware** (or from wherever you want):

```
class UserLogger
{
    public function init()
    {
        $logger = new Logger('order');
        $currUserId = Auth::id();
        $logPath = storage_path('logs/by_user/' . $currUserId . '/' . Carbon::now()->toDateString() . '.log');
        $logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler($logPath, Logger::INFO));

        return $logger;
    }
}
```

```
//app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php
class Authenticate
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $userLogger = new UserLogger();
        $logger = $userLogger->init();
        $context = ['some context data' => 'data'];
        $logger->info('custom user actions', $context);

     //...
```

- Laravel 8 version can be viewed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66380506/laravel-log-customer-log-file-with-userid-and-date/66535435#66535435)