# Laravel Log Customer Log file with UserId and date

Tags: laravel, logging

I need to track and update all the log activities by the user in a user log file with name of the log file has storage/log/{Auth::user()->}_26_02_2021.log.

How can I achieve this using Laravel Logger.

I searched google found no useful tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Let me only answer this question. How I found the solution to the above question.

I created a tap File like this inside a App\Logging folder

```
namespace App\Logging;

use Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\FormattableHandlerInterface;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
class CustomLogFilenames
{
    /**
     * Customize the given logger instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Log\Logger  $logger
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke($logger)
    {
        foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
            if ($handler instanceof RotatingFileHandler) {
                 $userId = auth()->user()->id;
                $handler->setFilenameFormat("{filename}-$userId-{date}", 'Y-m-d');
            }

            if ($handler instanceof FormattableHandlerInterface) {
                $handler->setFormatter(  new LineFormatter("[%datetime%]:  %message% \n", 'Y-m-d H:i:s', true));   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And added the following configuration inside the config\logging

```
    'userTracker' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'tap' => [App\Logging\CustomLogFilenames::class],
        'path' => storage_path('logs/user-id.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],
```

I added this in the Controller

```
   \Log::channel('userTracker')->info('Edit the  Page');
```

it created a file with name user-id-100-2020-02-26.log

Answer (score 0):

For this case you must create simple "**custom log formatter**" like this:

```
//app\Utils\Logs\UserLogger.php
class UserLogger
{

    public function __invoke(array $config): Logger
    {
        $log = new Logger($config['logname']);
        $level = $log::toMonologLevel($config['level'] ?: 'debug');

        $currUserId = auth()->user()->id;

        $logPath = storage_path('logs/by_user/' . $currUserId . '/' . Carbon::now()->toDateString() . '.log');
        $log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler($logPath, $level, false));

        return $log;
    }
}
```

- Also add three strings in your admin middleware for catching all users routes:

```
//app\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware.php
class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $uri = $request->path();
        $requestParams = $request->all();
        logs('by_user_logs')->info('this user want to: ', ['uri' => $uri, 'params' => $requestParams]);

//...
    }
}
```

- also add config params to config logging.php file:

```
//config\logging.php
'channels' => [
//...
        'by_user_logs' => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            'via' => UserLogger::class,
            'logname' => 'by_user_logs',
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],
//...
    ],
```

- this code tested for laravel 7 and 8
- you can see the full code listing [here](https://github.com/dionisvl/my.laravel.blog/commit/003b935d98461931ea86ec7d0cb17d7130f233a8)